# SRSS Break in merged Cells - Excel Export

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I'm quite sure there is no proper solution for this, so I'm interested in your ideas:
When you merge cells on a Report-File (rdl) and export it to excel, the Text won't break proper and the Cell won't become bigger height-wise.

In the Excel, the Cells shows the "Wrap Text" property, but it seems like it does nothing.

I still can't accept there is no Solution for this, does anyone have a good idea how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Matthias

Edit: [image]
[image]

I deleted some Fields, but as you can see, even the predefined Row-Height gets ignored on the Excel.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the issue please? Have you tried highlighting the whole sheet and auto sizing rows and columns?

Comment: Also if text is appearing in one column after an import, and you want it to appear in multiple, text-to-columns would be the easiest solution.

Comment: I edited with some Pictures: I have merged Cells in the "Header" before the Details-Grid starts, and there it doesn't break.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am having trouble understanding what you want. If you just want to make the text from your merged cells apear in one cell, you can select Just unmerge the cells. If you then want the text to be seperated into multiple other cells, you can use text-to-columns and set the deliminator as a regular old `space` character. I don't know anything about the program you are using to export to Excel, so I cannot help you on that end.

Comment: If you are having trouble with text not actually wrapping when it is exported, I get the same issue when I export to Excel from Access. I just highlight the whole sheet (using the box in the upper left hand corner of the grid area) and then click the Wrap text button once to turn it off, and then once again to turn it back on. That works for me, maybe it will work for you. Hope that helps.

Comment: I need to make this work from the Report, so the user doesn't have to do tht. So on the RDL-File itself.

Comment: Well I don't have the capability to use RDF files on my workstation, so I am not much help. I did find this link that seems to describe a slightly similar problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f103afb-90c5-441a-93ba-7e2beeda0071/autofit-column-width-in-table-cells-in-rdl-files?forum=sqlreportingservices). Sorry I couldn't be of more help, Good luck!